# Pandas: How to pivot rows into columns

Tags: python, pivot, transformation, pandas

I am looking for a way to pivot around 600 columns into rows. Here's a sample with only 4 of those columns (good, bad, ok, Horrible):

df:

```
RecordID   good   bad   ok  Horrible
  A          0      0    1     0 
  B          1      0    0     1
```

desired output:

```
 RecordID     Column    Value
   A           Good       0
   A            Bad       0
   A            Ok        1
   A          Horrible    0
   B           Good       1
   B            Bad       0
   B            Ok        0
   B          Horrible    1
```

Comment: If system performance is a concern to you, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66998050/15070697) from a real guru comparing the system performance of using .melt() vs .stack() for similar question.  Using .stack() is 2x faster for that similar case.  In general, if you want to maintain the sorting order of RecordID, you should use .stack() so that no extra sorting is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use melt function:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='RecordID', var_name='Column', value_name='Value')
   .sort_values('RecordID')
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
    RecordID      Column    Value
0          A        good        0
1          A         bad        0
2          A          ok        1
3          A    Horrible        0
4          B        good        1
5          B         bad        0
6          B          ok        0
7          B    Horrible        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) as follows.  Using [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) is preferred as it naturally resulted in rows already sorted in the order of `RecordID` so that **you don't need to waste processing time sorting** on it again, **especially important when you have a large number of columns**.

```
df = df.set_index('RecordID').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'Column', 0: 'Value'})
```

Output:

```
  RecordID    Column  Value
0        A      good      0
1        A       bad      0
2        A        ok      1
3        A  Horrible      0
4        B      good      1
5        B       bad      0
6        B        ok      0
7        B  Horrible      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data2 = {'RecordID': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'good': [0, 1, 1],
        'bad': [0, 0, 1],
        'horrible': [0, 1, 1],
        'ok': [1, 0, 0]}
  
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Melt data:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

```
melted = df.melt(id_vars='RecordID', var_name='Column', value_name='Value')
melted
```

[image]

Optionally: Group By - for summ or mean values:

```
f2 = melted.groupby(['Column']).sum()
df2
```

---

[image]

[image]