# How to pivot from columns to rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = [[1, 'tom', 10, 53, 2, 3, 9, 6 ], [2, 'nick', 1, 53, 2, 23, 4, 7], [3, 'juli', 9, 23, 2, 31, 9, 3]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Apple.Food.0', 'Apple.Food.1', 'Apple.Food.2', 'Pear.Food.0', 'Pear.Food.1', 'Pear.Food.2'])
  
df
```

| ID | Name | Apple.Food.0 | Apple.Food.1 | Apple.Food.2 | Pear.Food.0 | Pear.Food.1 | Pear.Food.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | 10 | 53 | 2 | 3 | 9 | 6 |
| 2 | nick | 1 | 53 | 2 | 23 | 4 | 7 |
| 3 | juli | 9 | 23 | 2 | 31 | 9 | 3 |

I want to unpack last 6 columns to like:
i.e. Apple.Food.0 - unpack prefix 'Apple' to the rows, unpack suffix '0' to the rows, keep 'Food' as the column name and keep the value there; then regenerate the ID column as the PK.

I tried to use .str.split() to split the column, however, the value will comes with all the spited columns. Any built-in pandas function could achieve this easily?

| ID | Name | Fruit | Time | Food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | Apple | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | tom | Apple | 1 | 53 |
| 3 | tom | Apple | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | tom | Pear | 0 | 3 |
| 5 | tom | Pear | 1 | 9 |
| 6 | tom | Pear | 2 | 6 |
| 7 | nick | Apple | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | nick | Apple | 1 | 53 |
| 9 | nick | Apple | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | nick | Pear | 0 | 23 |
| 11 | nick | Pear | 1 | 4 |
| 12 | nick | Pear | 2 | 7 |
| 13 | juli | Apple | 0 | 9 |
| 14 | juli | Apple | 1 | 23 |
| 15 | juli | Apple | 2 | 2 |
| 16 | juli | Pear | 0 | 31 |
| 17 | juli | Pear | 1 | 9 |
| 18 | juli | Pear | 2 | 3 |

Comment: df.melt` and then `.str.split`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex` with columns without `.` first, then [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with columns, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), check index names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and last add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['ID','Name'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack([0,2]).rename_axis(['ID','Name','Fruit','Time']).reset_index()
print (df1)
    ID  Name  Fruit Time  Food
0    1   tom  Apple    0    10
1    1   tom  Apple    1    53
2    1   tom  Apple    2     2
3    1   tom   Pear    0     3
4    1   tom   Pear    1     9
5    1   tom   Pear    2     6
6    2  nick  Apple    0     1
7    2  nick  Apple    1    53
8    2  nick  Apple    2     2
9    2  nick   Pear    0    23
10   2  nick   Pear    1     4
11   2  nick   Pear    2     7
12   3  juli  Apple    0     9
13   3  juli  Apple    1    23
14   3  juli  Apple    2     2
15   3  juli   Pear    0    31
16   3  juli   Pear    1     9
17   3  juli   Pear    2     3
```

Performance:

```
#3k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

def f1():
    df1 = df.set_index(['ID','Name'])
    df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
    df1 = df1.stack([0,2]).rename_axis(['ID','Name','Fruit','Time']).reset_index()
    
def f2():
    x = df.melt(['ID', 'Name'], value_name='Food')
    x[['Fruit', 'Time']] = x.variable.str.split('.', expand=True)[[0,2]]
    x = x.sort_values(['ID', 'Fruit']).reset_index(drop=True).drop('variable', 1)
    

In [41]: %timeit f1()
27.4 ms ± 1.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [42]: %timeit f2()
53.1 ms ± 1.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, how would you update ID column to have unique keys?

Comment: @VictorZhao - Sure, use `df['ID'] = range(1, len(df)+1)`